# Code execution halts for async function without written in then

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am trying to teach myself **async programming** in nodejs and I wrote this program to understand async programming better.

```
async function t(){
    
   for(let b = 0 ;b < 9000000000; b++){

   }

   console.log("Hello World 1")
}

t().then(() => {
    console.log("Hello World 2")
})

console.log("Hello World 3")
```

If this code block gets executed here is the log output

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 3
Hello World 2
```

Which is I think strange because the empty loop takes too long and therefore output should be

```
Hello World 3
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
```

since Hello World 3 is ready to be executed. Why **Hello World 3** is not executed first?

Comment: what is think is you are not performing anything async here. The for loop is running 9000000000 times so your program is stuck there. You call it async if you were using a setTimeOut

Comment: According to me what you want to achieve is multithreading but you are trying to implement async programming

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the idea of *asynchronous* behaviour in JavaScript.

JavaScript is a single-threaded language which means that **only one thing can execute at a time** on the main thread. So what does it mean for something to be *asynchronous*?

Operations like HTTP requests are asynchronous, but they aren't handled by JavaScript. The code we write simply initiates the asynchronous operation; the actual asynchronous operation is handled by the browser in the case of client-side JavaScript, or background threads or the operating system itself in the case of the NodeJS runtime.

In simple words, asynchronous operations take place in the background (outside of JavaScript land), and in the meantime, other things can execute on the main thread (in JavaScript land).

When the asynchronous operation is completed, our JavaScript code is notified, leading to the execution of the callback function that we provided at the time of initiating the asynchronous operation.

In your case, the problem is that there is a long-running loop that **executes on the main thread**. As a result, nothing else can execute while the loop is executing.

Following steps summarize how your code is executed:

1. Call function `t` and execute the code inside it. This all happens during the synchronous execution of the code. As a result, the long-running loop blocks the main thread
2. After the loop ends, log `'Hello World 1'` on the console
3. Function `t` ends; as a result, the promise returned by it is resolved with the value of `undefined`. The callback function of `t().then(...)` will be invoked asynchronously after the synchronous execution of the code ends
4. Log `"Hello World 3"` on the console
5. At this point, the synchronous execution of the code has ended. Now the queued tasks can be processed. In this case, we only have one queued task, i.e., the execution of the callback function of `t().then(...)`.

   The callback function is invoked asynchronously, logging `"Hello World 2"` to the console.

---

Following guide on the topic of asynchronous JavaScript is a good place to learn about this topic: [MDN - Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

### First of all your code is not async.

1. The first part `t()` will be executed which has no async function inside! So for executes and `hello world 1` prints.
2. Then promise stands by for idle in async mode! `hello world 3` prints.
3. Now its idle time to check if promise is fulfilled run `hello world 2`.

**You can change your code to this:**

```
async function t(){
    
   for(let b = 0 ;b < 9000000000; b++){

   }

   console.log("Hello World 1")
}

setTimeout(()=>{
   t().then(() => {
       console.log("Hello World 2")
   });
}, 1);

console.log("Hello World 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just writing async in front of function will not make it async. async will just make function return promise, but promise body executes right away. For example:

```
 const pr = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve()
 })

pr().then(() => {
    console.log('hello1')
 })
 console.log("Hello World 3")
```

Here hello1 will again execute first.
Only functions that are asynchronous will run later. for example fs module. It will run asynchronously not because it is wrapped in promise but because it was implemented in asynchronous manner. It uses libuv that in turn uses background threadpool to execute it asynchronously.
There are few ways to make your own code run asynchronously:

1. use setTimeout(() => {}, 0). With 0 millisecond your code will still actually run on main thread but it will only run after your main synchronous code is executed. This is not truly asynchronous(meaning heavy task load still runs on your main thread)
2. Use workerthreads. You can just spin up new thread where your code will run, this way your main thread will not be blocked.
3. Less recommended but fun way which I tried myself when I had same question as you in the past - use c++ api to build your own asynchronous function with nodegyp. It will use threadpool same way fs or crypto module use it. You can read more on C++ add-ons https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html. This is my repo where I test build it https://github.com/Edddo123/Native-Node-addons.
   Let me know if I can help you with anything else

Comment: Hey @edward can you go through the comments I posted in the question and tell me if I am thinking it right?

Comment: @HarshGupta Yes you are right, he is trying to implement async programming but setTimeout trick will not make it truly async